# Which Spring Integration Channel should be used for MQTT

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt

I am trying a demo app where we send commands over a UI which then goes through spring integration to deliver a command to a device and gives a command status back to UI, this is my first time using Spring Integration and am a bit unsure of the various implementations of channels. MQTT does not provide P2P direct communication, hence what channel should I use for Inbound and Outbound Adapters in my flow, PublishSubscribe or Direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to know more than "which channel type should I use?".

If you mean you want to send a command to the device and wait for a reply and send that reply to the browser, you need to turn an essentially asynchronous protocol into a synchronous request/reply scenario.

You would somehow need to to suspend the http request thread until the async reply from the device is received, correlate the reply to the request and release the request thread after handing over the reply to it.

You could simply do the correlation in your `@Controller` and send the replies to some other method in the controller, do the correlation there, and release the http thread.

```
<int-mqtt:inbound-channel-adapter channel="results" .../>
<int:channel id="results" />
<int:service-activator ref="myController" 
    method="someMethodToReceiveTheReplyAndCorrelateToRequest" />
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736993/how-to-send-basicack-to-inbound-adapter-after-publisher-confirm-from-outbound-ad/30737861#30737861) has one technique for a similar use case; we are [considering adding a component to the framework](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3736) to make such scenarios simpler to implement.

In any case, you would use `DirectChannel`s to connect the components.

If I have completely misunderstood your question, please clarify.

Comment: Thanks! Gary, that doesn't answer what I was looking for, but does answer a design related question for which I was browsing through your spring integration samples :-).

Comment: My question is, that if MQTT is basically a Pub/Sub protocol, will using DirectChannel, which I assume is default if i use `<int:channel id="foo" />` make any sense? & will it mandate a difference in Inbound adapter configuration and usage semantics if I use a PublishSubscribe channel?

Comment: The fact that MQTT is pub/sub is somewhat orthogonal to how you interface to it in a Spring Integration app. If you wish to deliver the same message to multiple recipients __within the same app__, you can either use n <`inbound-channel-adapter/>`s, each with a direct channel (yes that's the default), or a single `<inbound-channel-adapter/>` bound to a `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` and have each recipient subscribe to that channel. Obviously (hopefully it's obvious) the latter is more efficient because only one copy of the message hits the network. Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay, I have to send the same message to multiple devices at times, and receive heartbeat ping from them on a schedule, in some very specific conditions these messages will go to a single device. That ways it seems `<publish-subscribe-channel/>` will be a better option?

Comment: If they are all consuming from the same topic then you don't need pub/sub, MQTT will do it for you. Even if they subscribe to different topics, you can still achieve your use case with a single outbound adapter because you can select the topic for each message at runtime.